# How to give # in path in Karate

Tags: karate

I want to access - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-group-issues

But if I give # in path then it gets encoded to %23.

```
Feature: Sample Get Request
  Scenario: Sample Get Request
    Given url 'https://docs.gitlab.com/'
    And path 'ee/api/issues.html#list-group-issues'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

status code was: 404, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 823, url: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html%23list-group-issues,

However # in url works. Below snippet works. But I want to separate base url and path.

```
Feature: Sample Get Request
  Scenario: Sample Get Request
    Given url 'https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-group-issues'
#    And path 'ee/api/issues.html#list-group-issues'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Any pointers?

Kind Regards,

Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in Karate, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+headless

So you can use a back-slash to escape special characters. Try this example:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path '/\#bar'
* method get
```

And if you look at the response you will see:

```
"url": "https://httpbin.org/anything/#bar"
```

Which shows the request was encoded correctly.